# Javascript or Jquery get event any Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

i Have html code like this

```
<button>Button One</button>
<button>Button Two</button>
<button>Button Three</button>
<input type="Text" value="Content Text">
<a href="somewhere.php">URL</a>
```

I need Get event if any button click

i was tried use :

```
$(":button").click(function() {
    alert("button click");  
});
```

Thanks For Help

Comment: What you tried should have worked, can you provide an [MCVE](/help/mcve)?

Comment: Side note: Beware that if those buttons are in a form, they will submit it. The (surprising) default `type` of `button` elements is `"submit"`.

Comment: mostly you will have to use document ready handler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have will work thanks to jQuery's custom `:button` selector **provided** the buttons exist as of when you run your code. In order for them to exist, either:

1. You must have your code in a `script` element that's **after** the buttons in the HTML (just before the closing `</body>` tag is best), or
2. You must use jQuery's `ready` callback to wait until the elements have been created
3. You must delay execution of the code another way, such as a `window` `load` callback, but that's **very** late in the page load process

Note that using jQuery's custom CSS selectors may not be ideal, you might want to change `$(":button")` to `$("button")` or `$("button, input[type=button]")` so that jQuery can hand it off to the browser's built-in CSS selector engine.

Example of #1:

```html
<button>Button One</button>
<button>Button Two</button>
<button>Button Three</button>
<input type="Text" value="Content Text">
<a href="somewhere.php">URL</a>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(":button").click(function() {
    alert("button click");  
});
</script>
```

Example of #2:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() { // Or: `$(document).ready(function() {`, they're the same
  $(":button").click(function() {
    alert("button click");  
  });
});
</script>
<button>Button One</button>
<button>Button Two</button>
<button>Button Three</button>
<input type="Text" value="Content Text">
<a href="somewhere.php">URL</a>
```

Comment: sorry i was weekend with my family, yes that usefull, my mistake is the code not i put on $(document).ready(function(). thanks for the answer (y)

Answer (score 1):

Try this : remove `:`. This is tag selector which has no `.`, no `:` or no `#` but just tag name.

```
$("button").click(function() {
    alert("button click");  
});
```

More information on **[jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**

Comment: So your answer is to use the `button` selector, even though `:button` works. That's not going to be useful. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, yeah but as OP said it is not working.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar: Right. And if their code doesn't work, your code won't work. It's like answering the question "Why doesn't `if (a < b)` work?" with "Try `if (b >= a)`" -- if theirs didn't work, neither will the answer. It's frustrating, because the question is clearly missing important information. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `:` from your `.click` event.

There is a fiddle for you : http://jsfiddle.net/u1q6obLz/

Read more about jQuery selectors [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Actually, jQuery provides the [`:button` selector](http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/). The OP's code should work.